# IntelliJ can't see generated method

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javassist

I have a multimodular Maven project.

In module A I have a class to which I generate a new method with javassist (bytecode level) in compile time. When I decompile the class I can see that the method is really there.

In module B I want to call that generated method. It compiles and runs but IntelliJ is still reporting missing method.

It seems that IDE uses directly .java file from sibling module rather than compiled (and enhanced) version.

Is there any way how to tell IntelliJ to look at .class files and not .java if the file is not in this particular module?

Thanks

Comment: How can you modify with Javassist something at compile time? I thought Javassist worked only at load time hence when your .class is mounted into the JVM

Comment: Check https://github.com/hielkehoeve/maven-javassist